# Erro ao realizar edição através do SQLITE

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sqlite, android-fragment

Estou tentando editar uma informação que está salva no bando SQLITE.
Estou trabalhando com fragmentes.
 Mas estou com o seguinte erro:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement, PID: 11997
                                                                                           android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement/com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.adicionar_usuario}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                                                                                               at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.usuario$UsuarioAdapter$2.onClick(usuario.java:218)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Tenho uma listview com todos os contatos, e em cada contato tenho um icone para editar e para deletar. 
O editar seria o seguinte:`

```
ImageView editarBt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editar);
            editarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), adicionar_usuario.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nome", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNome());
                    intent.putExtra("email", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getEmail());
                    intent.putExtra("np", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNp());
                    intent.putExtra("tipoFunc", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getTipoFunc());
                    intent.putExtra("id", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getId());
                   getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Quando eu clico em editar acontece o erro.

Tentei trocar esses intent esse código:`

```
 ImageView editarBt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editar);
            editarBt.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("nome", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNome());
                    data.putString("email", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getEmail());
                    data.putString("np", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getNp());
                    data.putString("tipoFunc", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getTipoFunc());
                    data.putInt("id", listaUser.get(auxPosition).getId());
                    Fragment fragment = new adicionar_usuario();
                    fragment.setArguments(data);




                }
            });
`
```

Alguém sabe me informar o motivo desse erro?

Comment: Você tem uma classe chamada `adicionar_usuario`? Ela não está declarada no AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ela é um Fragment, por isso não está no manifest. @LeonardoDias

Comment: Eu acredito que esse seja o problema então, você não pode fazer um Intent pra um Fragment, você tem que usar o FragmentManager e alterar o FrameLayout com o Fragment desejado

Comment: @LeonardoDias você teria um exemplo disso? por favor?

Comment: Coloquei o código de exemplo na resposta Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas,

Quando você vai colocar um Fragment em alguma Activity, você usa o seguinte código:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, adicionar_usuario, "adicionar usuário")
                .commit();
```

E no Layout, você deve ter um FrameLayout com o id `container`, exemplo:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Você já deve ter feito isso pra declarar esse Fragment atual que você colocou o código ai.

Qualquer dúvida grita ai.

Comment: eu editei minha  pergunta com essas dicas.